# how to use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()?

Tags: android

i'm trying to create txt file under external memory by using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() but when i run program no file created .
i try to create file under DCIM folder.

here is the code:

```
 public void process4(View view){
        PrintWriter pw=null;
        String s=et.getText().toString();
        File folder= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        File f=new File(folder,"cach.txt");

        try {
            pw=new PrintWriter(f);
            pw.println(s);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if(pw!=null) {
                pw.close();
            }
        }
}
```

process4() will call when i press button;

Comment: Remove quotes from "folder" in new File()

Comment: @Orlangure i am using physical device as an emulator can this file is visible non root physical device???

Comment: The problem is not related to root or emulator; you are trying to create the file inside a directory called "folder" instead of referencing DCIM folder from folder variable of type File that you get with getExternalStorageDirectory

Comment: @Orlangure when i change "folder" to folder nothing will changes